# Как сериализовать поле класса, которое является объектом, описанным в другой сборке(dll)?

Tags: c#, сериализация, google-protobuf

Я использую *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll* в моем проекте. У меня есть класс, свойство этого класса является объектом, который был описан в *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll* и подключен к моему проекту.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class FunctionAnnotation : 
{
     [ProtoMember(1)] public IMethodSymbol Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

`IMethodSymbol` описан в *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll*.
Я использую *protobuf-net*.
При попытке сериализовать объект он бросает исключение:

> No serializer defined for type: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMetnodSymbol.

Понятно, что  *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMetnodSymbol* не помечен как *[ProtoContract]*.

```
private void Serialization()
{
     string folderName = @"f:/serialization/";
     Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
     int name = this.Symbol.ToString().GetHashCode();
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("f:/serialization/" + name + ".dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
     {
          Serializer.Serialize(fs, this);
     }
}
```

Как решить эту проблему? Есть ли варианты не вручную помечать классы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из вариантов - воспользоваться суррогатным объектом и аттрибутами "Before/After".

Это довольно трудоемко - придется интерпретировать интерфейс самому.
В этом примере кода - самый базовый вариант, который можно расширить полиморфным суррогатом.

```
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace ProtobufSurrogate
{
    public class ProtobufTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CanSerializeWithBeforeAndAfter()
        {
            var original = new FunctionAnnotation { Symbol = new ConcreteMethodSymbol1 { Arity = 123} };
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, original);
                stream.Position = 0;
                var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<FunctionAnnotation>(stream);
                Assert.AreEqual(123, deserialized.Symbol.Arity);
            }
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class FunctionAnnotation
    {
        public IMethodSymbol Symbol { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        private MethodSymbolSurrogate SymbolSurrogate { get; set; }

        [ProtoBeforeSerialization]
        private void BeforeSerialization()
        {
            SymbolSurrogate = MethodSymbolSurrogate.ToSurrogate(Symbol);
        }

        [ProtoAfterSerialization]
        private void AfterSerialization()
        {
            SymbolSurrogate = null;
        }

        [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
        private void AfterDeserialization()
        {
            Symbol = SymbolSurrogate.ToMethodSymbol();
            SymbolSurrogate = null;
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class MethodSymbolSurrogate
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Arity { get; set; }

        public IMethodSymbol ToMethodSymbol()
        {
            return new ConcreteMethodSymbol1 {Arity = Arity};
        }

        public static MethodSymbolSurrogate ToSurrogate(IMethodSymbol symbol)
        {
            return new MethodSymbolSurrogate {Arity = symbol.Arity};
        }
    }

    public interface IMethodSymbol
    {
        int Arity { get; }
    }

    class ConcreteMethodSymbol1 : IMethodSymbol
    {
        public int Arity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Есть сомнение, что экземпляр этого интерфейса будет иметь какой-либо смысл после десериализации.

Comment: Допустим Aritry не int, а другой тип, который не поддерживает protobuf, что тогда делать ? Опять писать следующий класс суррогат... для поддержки этого типа?